# custom loop issue

Tags: customization, loop

I am trying to get a custom loop to work and I can not see why it is failing.

```
    $args = array( 'category_name' => 'audio', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ); 
    $sound = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if( $sound->have_posts()): 



     while ( $sound->have_posts()) : $sound->the_post();
         $file = get_attached_media('audio'); 

        foreach( $file as $data) { ?>
            <li><a href="#" data-src="<?php echo $data->guid; ?>" class="tracks" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Right now there is one post in the category. I had 6 but only 5 showed up on the page. So I deleted them all and started over. I made one post. Nothing shows. When I do a var dump of the $file variable, I get this

```
  array(0){

  }
```

shouldn't there be a "post" object there? is my loop messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used this inside the loop

```
 get_post_meta();
```

to get the results I wanted. The audio url is stored in the wp_postmeta table. I opened it up and looked for the content that I was trying to get. I found it and it had the key of "enclosure". I don't know why it would have that key but it did. So I then could do this

```
 $audioUrl = strtok(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', true), "\n"); ?>
```

I used strtok() because for some reason, there were some other characters added to the url at the end. They were on a new line. I don't know what they mean. so what was returned was this

```
 string "http://example.com/audio.mp3
         677
         audio/mpeg
```

so the strtok function took of the last two lines and left me with a nice clean address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the Id of the post type.

Change

```
 $file = get_attached_media('audio'); To
 $file = get_attached_media('audio',get_the_ID());
```

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

Comment: No joy there. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Could you try to remove the audio.
And change the code to  
    $file = get_attached_media('',get_the_ID());
   var_dump()</pre> the new $file and check the results

Comment: The loop does work. If I add the_content(); then I get what should be there. I attached an audio file to the post and I am trying to get just the url of the file. instead, the content returns an audio tag with all the information some of which I want.

Comment: @Jamie 
By attach do you mean put it in the editor?

Comment: Also try to print_r() and check. If it still does not display anything check your attachment in the media section and see if it has been attached or not?

Comment: I used the attached media button in the editor to add the audio. It makes an audio html tag in the content. The other way I found that could work to get the url is by using get_post_meta(get_the_ID()); this produces an array that has the data I want, I just haven't been able to figure out how to access the array yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you said "Right now there is one post in the category". Are you sure you have attached a audio media for the post ? If yes,try this

1.Inside while loop var dump the post id. var_dump(get_the_ID);
2.If you get that correct then the problem is with audio media.

Answer (score 0):

You can try showing `the_title()` in your loop query. To make sure your query is working :

```
while ( $sound->have_posts() ) : $sound->the_post();
    $file = get_attached_media( 'audio' ); 
    the_title(); // show the title post
        foreach( $file as $data ) { 
        ?><li><a href="#" data-src="<?php 
            echo $data->guid; ?>" class="tracks" title="<?php 
            the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php 
            the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
    }
endwhile;
```

If `the_title()` in post shows and audio doesn't show, make sure you have attached the audio file.